# How to modify Jquery accordion menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Good afternoon, I have a problem with my Jquery accordion menu. Example if I click on submenu then it should close others and open this submenu (with nested submenu), without closing it and then open it. Thank you very much. Please forgive my bad english.

Website: [link](http://www.odsavacky.cz/produkty/)

HTML:

```
<ul class="arrows_list1-1">
   <h3>Naše produkty</h3>
   <div class="menu-produkty-container">
      <ul id="menu-produkty" class="menu">
         <li id="menu-item-97" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-wpccategories menu-item-has-children menu-item-97">
            <a href="http://www.odsavacky.cz/wpccategories/akce/">Akce</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
               <li id="menu-item-114" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-wpccategories menu-item-114">
                  <a href="http://www.odsavacky.cz/wpccategories/akcni-ceny/">Akční ceny</a>
               </li>
               <li id="menu-item-98" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-wpccategories menu-item-98">
                  <a href="http://www.odsavacky.cz/wpccategories/novinky/">Novinky</a>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li id="menu-item-63" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-wpccategories current-wpccategories-ancestor current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current-wpccategories-parent menu-item-has-children menu-item-63">
            <a href="http://www.odsavacky.cz/wpccategories/spotrebni-material/">Spotřební materiál</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
               <li id="menu-item-66" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-wpccategories menu-item-has-children menu-item-66">
                  <a href="http://www.odsavacky.cz/wpccategories/kyslikova-terapie/">Kyslíková terapie</a>
                  <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
                     <li id="menu-item-67" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-wpccategories menu-item-67">
                        <a href="http://www.odsavacky.cz/wpccategories/kyslikove-masky-a-nosni-sondy/">Kyslíkové masky a nosní sondy</a>
                     </li>
                     <li id="menu-item-176" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-wpccategories menu-item-176">
                        <a href="http://www.odsavacky.cz/wpccategories/masky-inhalacni/">Masky inhalační</a>
                     </li>
                     <li id="menu-item-68" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-wpccategories menu-item-68">
                        <a href="http://www.odsavacky.cz/wpccategories/mikronebulizatory/">Mikronebulizátory</a>
                     </li>
                     <li id="menu-item-179" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-wpccategories menu-item-179">
                        <a href="http://www.odsavacky.cz/wpccategories/prutokomery/">Průtokoměry</a>
                     </li>
                     <li id="menu-item-180" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-wpccategories menu-item-180">
                        <a href="http://www.odsavacky.cz/wpccategories/redukcni-ventily/">Redukční ventily</a>
                     </li>
                     <li id="menu-item-178" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-wpccategories menu-item-178">
                        <a href="http://www.odsavacky.cz/wpccategories/prislusenstvi-k-tep-nebulizatorum/">Příslušenství k tep. nebulizátorům</a>
                     </li>
                     <li id="menu-item-175" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-wpccategories menu-item-175">
                        <a href="http://www.odsavacky.cz/wpccategories/kyslikove-zvlhcovace-prislusenstvi/">Kyslíkové zvlhčovače, příslušenství</a>
                     </li>
                     <li id="menu-item-181" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-wpccategories menu-item-181">
                        <a href="http://www.odsavacky.cz/wpccategories/studene-nebulizatory-prislusenstvi/">Studené nebulizátory, příslušenství</a>
                     </li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
               <li id="menu-item-73" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-wpccategories menu-item-has-children menu-item-73">
                  <a href="http://www.odsavacky.cz/wpccategories/resuscitace-intubace/">Resuscitace, intubace</a>
                  <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
                     <li id="menu-item-189" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-wpccategories menu-item-189">
                        <a href="http://www.odsavacky.cz/wpccategories/laryngoskopy/">Laryngoskopy</a>
                     </li>
                     <li id="menu-item-188" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-wpccategories menu-item-188">
                        <a href="http://www.odsavacky.cz/wpccategories/laryngealni-masky/">Laryngeální masky</a>
                     </li>
                     <li id="menu-item-190" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-wpccategories menu-item-190">
                        <a href="http://www.odsavacky.cz/wpccategories/masky-resuscitacni/">Masky resuscitační</a>
                     </li>
                     <li id="menu-item-192" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-wpccategories menu-item-192">
                        <a href="http://www.odsavacky.cz/wpccategories/rucni-resuscitatory/">Ruční resuscitátory</a>
                     </li>
                     <li id="menu-item-191" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-wpccategories menu-item-191">
                        <a href="http://www.odsavacky.cz/wpccategories/prislusenstvi-defibrilace/">Příslušenství defibrilace</a>
                     </li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
               <li id="menu-item-71" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-wpccategories menu-item-has-children menu-item-71">
                  <a href="http://www.odsavacky.cz/wpccategories/odsavani/">Odsávání</a>
                  <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
                     <li id="menu-item-182" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-wpccategories menu-item-182">
                        <a href="http://www.odsavacky.cz/wpccategories/odsavaci-cevky/">Odsávací cévky</a>
                     </li>
                     <li id="menu-item-183" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-wpccategories menu-item-183">
                        <a href="http://www.odsavacky.cz/wpccategories/odsavaci-hadice/">Odsávací hadice</a>
                     </li>
                     <li id="menu-item-184" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-wpccategories menu-item-184">
                        <a href="http://www.odsavacky.cz/wpccategories/odsavaci-lahve/">Odsávací lahve</a>
                     </li>
                     <li id="menu-item-185" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-wpccategories menu-item-185">
                        <a href="http://www.odsavacky.cz/wpccategories/odsavaci-vaky/">Odsávací vaky</a>
                     </li>
                     <li id="menu-item-186" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-wpccategories menu-item-186">
                        <a href="http://www.odsavacky.cz/wpccategories/saci-filtry/">Sací filtry</a>
                     </li>
                     <li id="menu-item-187" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-wpccategories menu-item-187">
                        <a href="http://www.odsavacky.cz/wpccategories/stopventily/">Stopventily</a>
                     </li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
               <li id="menu-item-70" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-wpccategories menu-item-70">
                  <a href="http://www.odsavacky.cz/wpccategories/narkotizace-umela-plicni-ventilace/">Narkotizace, umělá plicní ventilace</a>
               </li>
               <li id="menu-item-64" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-wpccategories current-menu-item menu-item-64">
                  <a href="http://www.odsavacky.cz/wpccategories/diagnostika/">Diagnostika</a>
               </li>
               <li id="menu-item-65" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-wpccategories menu-item-65">
                  <a href="http://www.odsavacky.cz/wpccategories/ekg-prislusenstvi/">EKG – příslušenství</a>
               </li>
               <li id="menu-item-69" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-wpccategories menu-item-69">
                  <a href="http://www.odsavacky.cz/wpccategories/monitoring-defibrilace/">Monitoring, defibrilace</a>
               </li>
               <li id="menu-item-72" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-wpccategories menu-item-72">
                  <a href="http://www.odsavacky.cz/wpccategories/operacni-svetla/">Operační světla</a>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li id="menu-item-75" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-wpccategories menu-item-has-children menu-item-75">
            <a href="http://www.odsavacky.cz/wpccategories/zdravotnicke-pristroje/">Zdravotnické přístroje</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
               <li id="menu-item-76" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-wpccategories menu-item-76">
                  <a href="http://www.odsavacky.cz/wpccategories/kyslikova-terapie-zdravotnicke-pristroje/">Kyslíková terapie</a>
               </li>
               <li id="menu-item-77" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-wpccategories menu-item-77">
                  <a href="http://www.odsavacky.cz/wpccategories/resuscitace-intubace-zdravotnicke-pristroje/">Resuscitace, intubace</a>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li id="menu-item-74" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-wpccategories menu-item-74">
            <a href="http://www.odsavacky.cz/wpccategories/vyukovy-program/">Výukový program</a>
         </li>
         <li id="menu-item-62" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-wpccategories menu-item-62">
            <a href="http://www.odsavacky.cz/wpccategories/nahradni-dily/">Náhradní díly</a>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</ul>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf('http://www.odsavacky.cz/blog/wpcproduct/') != -1 ){
        $('.arrows_list1-1 li ul').hide();
        var prev_url = document.referrer;
        var $current = $('.arrows_list1-1 li a[href="' + prev_url + '"]');
        $current.parents('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
        $current.next('.sub-menu').slideToggle();    
    }else{  
        $('.arrows_list1-1 li ul').hide();
        $('.arrows_list1-1 li').click(function(ev) {
            $(this).find('>ul').slideToggle();
            ev.stopPropagation();
        });

        var url = window.location.href;
        var $current = $('.arrows_list1-1 li a[href="' + url + '"]');
        $current.parents('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
        $current.next('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
    }
$('#menu-produkty > li > a').after('<p class="border_bottom"></span>');
$('.more-icon a').addClass('eModal-1');

var product = /([\w\-]+)\/$/.exec(url)[1];
$("input[name='your-product']").val(product);  
)};
```

Comment: I'm currently not in the position to read all your code. What i would do is have one container div for the header you click and the items below it. Both of them in there own class. The items list would have a default height of 0px. On click set height of all those classes back to 0px and open the on belonging to this class. You can calculate the height with javascript how much list items are in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know exactly if my example works in your code, but the idea is as following:
The moment you open an item, you add a class. When you click another item, you close all those classes, and open the clicked item.

```
$('.arrows_list1-1 li').click(function(ev) {
    $('.OpenedMenu').slideUp();// slide all current items closed
    $(this).find('>ul').slideToggle().addClass('OpenedMenu'); // add the class to the ul's
    ev.stopPropagation();
});
```